# Is there any setup option to use binary prefixes

Tags: gnome, nautilus, files, filemanager, binary

It would be better to see file sizes in binary units (i.e.: MiB) for my job everywhere in Ubuntu (at least Gnome would be perfect.)

So my question:
Is there any global setup option to use binary prefixes everywhere in Ubuntu (or at least Nautilus or sg else)?

Comment: see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=867085

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have got an answer to my question, it would be good to reopen to response it (probably it could be useful to others,there are two similar question what are closed also).

Comment: As I noted in 2014 I had an answer!!! Please, reopen it!!!